# Is there any advantage of using Expo or CRNA when must have to eject?

Tags: react-native

I have developed only by native CLI since I started RN, but I have become interested in CRNA or Expo recently.

But if I want to use a library which expo does not support, I heard I have to do a `eject`.

I often make mobile apps for IoT products, so I think I should use Bluetooth or Wi-Fi library, so I think I should use a library that is not supported by expo unconditionally.

In such an environment where an unconditional `eject` must be made, does using expo or crna have advantages over using the native CLI?

Answer (score 0):

One possible advantage of using Expo even after ejecting is that after ejecting, you can opt to have a native project linked to *ExpoKit*. *ExpoKit* is a native library that allows you some of the same conveniences that you would have when using the Expo client.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html